# Frame rate drop in android 3.0 and higher devices why?

Tags: java, android, performance, bitmap, android-canvas

Drawing bitmap on canvas using " RectF " is slower in nexus7 (dual or quad core..some 1-2 gb ram) version4.3 compared to my old device galaxy y version2.3.3 (256mb ram 800mhz)

i am totally confused ,what am i missing ,Is it related to hardware acceleration,sdk  ?

can some one please explain me old vs new sdk performance

Comment: How do you draw the bitmap on the canvas? Code?

Comment: dst.set(0, 0,width,Height);  
c.drawBitmap(image,null,dst,null);

Comment: In this code i am filling the rectangle to scale image automatically EVERY FRAME (i need it that way)... so my question is why is it slower on nexus 7 - i mean it should be working faster compared to samsung y

Comment: Are more physical pixels involved on the nexus tablet?  If so, there may be substantially more work to do, outweighing any increase in throughput.